# How can I fix Client DOM Code Injection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, code-injection, checkmarx

How can I fix a Client DOM Code Injection  problem on JS? Can anyone help me?

The problem is below:

[image]

Red boxs are show where is the problem. But I don't have any idea how can I resolve it.

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: this js file using on  mywebsite  then use checkmarx scan for vulnerability i have getting this report.

Comment: you can use escape, encode functions or regex to test url parameter.